# API Limit Issue

Tags: api

We are getting API Limit exception and I am not able to see which job/application is creating this issue. I am not able to see any debug log or scheduled jobs/Apex Jobs/Background Jobs/Bulk Data Load jobs.

Can anyone help me out how to check this issue. I searched some blogs but not able to get correct information. I don't have much information to share on this issue.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is this an everyday thing or did this just happen once? If once, did someone do a data load job that day? Maybe they used a scope of 1 thus using an API call for each record.

Comment: it is happening from last week. To be accurate from last Monday.

Comment: What changed in the use of your org? New process added, new external service, new anything? It typically does not happen just out of the blue unless in the case of the data loader with scope size of 1

Answer (score 6):

There is a built-in report that breaks down your API usage over the last 7 days.  You can find it and save it by going to this url:

```
https://#####.salesforce.com/00O?rt=104&retURL=%2F00O&c=UN&c=FULL_NAME&c=EM&c=CID&c=TS&c=CC&duel0=FULL_NAME%2CUN%2CEM&scope=organization&details=yes
```

You'll need to replace `#####` with your Salesforce instance or MyDomain.  It's a pretty limited report and will only break down the usage by day, but it will show you which user and application is using the API most.

Comment: By the way... If you use login.salesforce.com it will automatically send a user to the report if they're already logged in, or prompt to login otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

I've written about this in [Monitoring your Salesforce API usage](http://www.fishofprey.com/2016/06/monitoring-your-salesforce-api-usage.html).

In addition to the [API Usage Last 7 Days report the Drew pointed out](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/181914/102) there are a few other options.

You can get real time usage data directly via the API from both the [REST API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_limits.htm) and the [SOAP API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_header_limitinfo.htm).

If you really want detailed information you can use the [Event Monitoring API](http://www.fishofprey.com/2016/06/monitoring-your-salesforce-api-usage.html#EventMonitoring) (which will be a paid feature). This will give details right down to every request being made.

Answer (score 0):

I have also been fighting with this issue before, multiple times actually. There is a way, how to investigate with Event Logs.

Salesforce offers a built-in summary of API calls through its Event Monitoring tool. While the documentation implies that you need to acquire the Event Monitoring add-on for tool access, the API Total Usage log that we require is available free of charge. The only prerequisite is to activate the "Generate event log files" option within the Event Monitoring section.

Consequently, all API calls directed towards Salesforce within the preceding day (from midnight to midnight) were recorded in a log file named "APITotalUsage". This log is accessible through the following Heroku App: https://salesforce-elf.herokuapp.com.

There are several options available to visualize the data, including CRM Analytics (if you possess the license). However, if you have at least basic knowledge of APIs in your environment, simple Excel will do.

Comment: Example for working with Event Monitoring Logs are here: https://www.aboutsalesforce.com/2023/10/how-to-use-event-logs-to-debug.html